# Quadratic Programming "big M" method

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

How does the optimization problem

$$\min_{x,\eta} \frac{1}{2} x^TGx+x^Tc+M\eta$$
$$ s.t. Ax+\eta-b \geq0$$
$$\eta\geq0$$

look in standard form? What would the KKT look like?

The problem is, that I've got a solver that needs the standard
$$\min_{x} \frac{1}{2} x^TGx+x^Tc$$
$$ s.t. Ax-b \geq0$$
as input format.
I tried to use the substitution $y=[x \quad \eta]^T$. Then the problem is
$$\min_{y} \frac{1}{2} y^T\begin{bmatrix}G & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}y+y^T\begin{bmatrix}c\\M\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ s.t. [A\quad 1]y-b \geq0$$
$$\eta\geq0$$
but with this problem the 'new' G- matrix $\begin{bmatrix}G & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$  is singular and the solver can't solve the problem any more.

Comment: I think the problem is in the solver, What algorithm is it implementing? Why it doesn't work with a singular matrix? Interior-point methods or active set methods should work fine with singula matrices I think.

Comment: I'm using an active set method for solving the QP with a Null Space Method. The problem is, that when I initialize my active set algorithm, there is no active constraint and therefore no NullSpace exists. If this happens, I want to solve the QP via a direct solution of the KKT- system, but this is not possible due to the singularity of G. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Please share if you reached any improvement so far.

Comment: Yes, I did an improvement. The idea is to use a quadratic penalization of the constraint violation rather than a linear one. In doing so, the 'new' G- matrix holds the old G and ones on its diagonal (no zeros). Eta becomes a vector holding the violation of every individual constraint. In doing so, the 'new' G is no longer singular and the solver works fine.